# heroku feedzirra problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, feedzirra

is that feedzirra compatible with heroku ?
i have no problem at localhost to use feezirra.

Comment: What is the error that you are getting while using feedzirra with heroku?

Comment: 500 error.

We're sorry, but something went wrong.

We've been notified about this issue and we'll take a look at it shortly.

Comment: Look at your logs. The error 500 means something is wrong in your application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm currently using Feedzirra on Heroku (Ruby 1.9.2) without any problem.

Comment: any tutorial to install feedzirra at heroku ?

Comment: It is not different than installing it in any other platform. Add the Gem to your `Gemfile`, then run `$ bundle install`